# How to set use Ubuntu python after installing conda?

Tags: 16.04, python3, python-2.7, anaconda

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I installed `anaconda3` and I know that Ubuntu comes with Python 2.7, and I still want to use it aside from conda's version of Python.

When I use `python` or `python3`, they both refer to conda's Python. How can I change it so that `python` would refer to Ubuntu's Python 2.7 and leave `python3` to call for Python 3.7 from conda?

[image: Both python and python3 are the same]

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin:/home/mohammed/bin:/home/mohammed/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ which python
/home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin/python

$ which python3
/home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Comment: Hello and wellcome to askUbuntu. Can you please add the output of `which python` and `which python3`? I hope I can help you with knowing the output.

Comment: Pls add to question output of echo $PATH

Comment: That's the output of echo $PATH   /home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin:/home/mohammed/bin:/home/mohammed/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
The output of which python is    /home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin/python
    
The output of which python3 is  /home/mohammed/anaconda3/bin/python3  
they both are the same, so I wanted to change python to refer to usr/bin/python
is that possible?

Comment: So you likely have a "PATH=-/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" or some such line in .bashrc or .profile. Remove or comment it out. Also pls **edit in** these infos into your question. Better than comments

Answer (score 0):

You can define your script's platform of execution through your `shebang`.

All you have to do is add at the first line of your python file, the full path to your 2.7 python (e.g. "#!/usr/bin/python2").

If that doesn't answers your question, please make further clarification to be provided with a more optimal answer.